# findViewById must not be null

Tags: android, kotlin

I am building an eCommerce app where I want to show the added items of cart in a new Activity.
I want to access a View in another activity whose set content view is a different layout, how to achieve this?

What I Did is that I have created a layout for the cart icon and image
then I Inflate that to menu options to look like a cart

I am using Android Studio 3.5.1

findViewById(R.id.cartIcon) must not be null

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You cannot access the view in another activity. You should inform the activity through activity results, or even a singleton and once the Activity with the cart icon is on the foreground again to update the icon.

Comment: @falcon17, include that layout in XML or as a fragment inside in fragmentContainerView or create a dialog of that view depending upon the requirement. You can't access any control without their view reference.

Answer (score 0):

you should use something like shared preferences,intents, or sql to share data between activities and then upadate the UI of that activity using the shared data